# My integer comes out wrong when reading input from console

Tags: c#

The age variable always comes out "49". Here is my code...

```
using System;

namespace testCS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name = "Bob";
            int age = 0;

            Console.Write("What is your name? ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);

            Console.Write("How old are you? ");
            age = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine(name + ", age " + age);

            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for `Console.Read`, and compare that with what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Ah @mason Thanks. I jumped the gun on that one!

Comment: Use "C# for the strong", not "C# for a weak" :)

Comment: For those that are downvoting or voting to close as unclear, mind stating why? I feel like this is a good example of a question that a new programmer would have issues with and that might (temporarily) pass by someone more experienced in the language.

Comment: I agree with @mason.  The problem statement is clear and the OP has provided the code that illustrates that problem.  I think the downvotes are unwarranted.

Comment: 49 is 0x31 is ASCII '1', so you're probably between 15 and 19 (I don't think you're below 15 years old, although possible). Wait a couple of years and you're getting 50 ;-) (= 0x32 ='2', because you're 20-something...)

Comment: @ChrisDunaway It was unclear 'til it was edited. The question appears to have no research done whatsoever.

Comment: @cybermonkey - I looked back at the original draft of the question.  It is not substantially different than it is now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `Console.Read()`. That reads a character and returns its codepoint as an `int`. You should use

```
int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

That will read a line as a `string` and then convert it to an int.

You can also use `int.TryParse()`, which will try to parse a string and return `true` if successful.

```
int age;
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, out age)) 
{
    // success
}
else
{
    // invalid input
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to parse the input before assigning it to an int.

```
age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

The `Console.Read()` method return the caracter code of what you input in the console.

Answer (score 3):

`Console.Read` *does* return an `int`, but it is a *character code*, not an integer read from the command line.

[Console.Read Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

Instead, you should use `ReadLine` and then `TryParse` or `Parse`.

Answer (score 2):

[Console.Read()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) reads one character and returns an integer, which is an old-fashioned [ASCII](http://www.ascii-code.com/) character code.

So if you type in **18** Console.Read() will

- read the first character 1
- convert the character '1' to ASCII which is 49
- return the integer 49

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to all the solutions posted here, inspired by [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4826740/max-poshusta)'s (now removed) comment on the question.

```
using System;

namespace testCS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name = "Bob";
            string age = "";

            Console.Write("What is your name? ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);

            Console.Write("How old are you? ");
            age = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(name + ", age " + age);

            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, if you don't plan to use math to manipulate the age, and you have no particular need to enforce that `age` be a number, then you can use a string as the data type for the age variable, and make sure to read the entire line when the user enters the age. Now you can enter "49", "50.5", "old", "young", "about 24 months" for the age and the program will still work. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, this may be acceptable.